# Why Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo) returns false?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute below lines in chrome console.

```
function Foo() {}
console.log(Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo)); // false
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object)); //true
```

The second line prints false while third line prints true. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

It happens because all Objects is an object, even its prototype.

But the Foo's prototype (Foo.prototype) is an object different from Foo.

See the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score 1):

`Foo.prototype` is not the prototype of the Foo function itself.  It is the prototype of any object created using `new Foo()`.  The function `Foo`'s prototype is just `Function.prototype`.

```
console.log(Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo)); // true
console.log(Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Foo())); // true
```

In the case of Object.prototype, this is the very top of the prototype chain and will return true for anything that doesn't otherwise explicitly break the prototype chain.  In the case of Object, since it's a constructor function:

```
console.log(typeof Object); // function
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true
```

And because Function.prototype is itself an object, then:

```
console.log(Object.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

This is why `console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object));` is true, because Object.prototype exists within the prototype chain of the Object constructor function.  Specifically it's the prototype of the prototype of the function.

Here is a diagram of how these objects and functions are related.  Blue rectangles represent objects, rounded green rectangles are functions (which are a special type of object).  The thick black lines are the prototype chain of each object, and the dashed lines show how objects are related using the `.prototype` property of constructor functions.
[image: Javascript prototype chain]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination.
console.log(Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo); **// true**
The text in bold should be false in your answer. Please correct it.

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal No, Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo) is definitely true if Foo is a function.  You can try it in the console.  Here's a fiddle showing some of the prototype chains: https://jsfiddle.net/931e33an/3/

Comment: sorry my bad. However, it seems there is syntax error in below line. You are missing parentheses ")" at the end which you can correct.
console.log(Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo)); // true